I can't connect with gradio to share public link after using ngrok and fastapi to build backend
Colab notebook detected. This cell will run indefinitely so that you can see errors and logs. To turn off, set debug=False in launch().
Could not create share link. Please check your internet connection or our status page: https://status.gradio.app.
2024/12/01 17:13:43 [W] [service.go:132] login to server failed: dial tcp 44.237.78.176:7000: connect: connection refused
this is my error (image) 
How can i fix the eror

You are simply copy-pasting the error message you are getting. With just that, it is hard to tell what is happening. Please edit the post to include more details of your application and environment, and a minimal reproducible example.
